# What to do when crib dragging does not work for OTP ciphers?

Tags: one-time-pad

```
7ECC555AB95BF6EC605E5F22B772D2B34FF4636340D32FABC29B
73CB4855BE44F6EC60594C2BB47997B60EEE303049CD3CABC29B
64C6401BAF45F6A930435F3DF875C4E102F8742A45C824AFCA9B
7AC24F5EAF17F0A0754D5834BC3CC3A90ABD7B2A52C222ABC89B
72C24A52B550B3B8624D4F22F86BD2B30ABD642C498122A1D29B
73CC5457BF17E7A4750C5423B178D0A44FFF756355C03CABC28A
74CC0155B443B3A8795F4224AA7E97B507F2632606CF3FA0D59B
```

This was given to us as a question so it is possible to solve, but how could you do this? I have tried MANY words and crib dragged them, there is just too many possibilities to deduce them all, there must be an easier way to do this.

It is assumed that each line is a different message encrypted with the same pad.